# Implement runnable for class whose main purpose is not to be runnable (coding-style)

Tags: java, coding-style, runnable

I'm programming an boss timer for Guild Wars 2. I have a `Boss` class which contains all related game events and an `update()` method to get the current event statuses form the API.

To lower the update time for all bosses I want to parallelize the requests.

Now I could easily implement the `Runnable` interface in my `Boss` class and call the `update()` method in the `run()` method.

After that I would iterate over all bosses, pass them into an `Executor`'s `execute()` method and wait until all bosses are updated.

Is there anything wrong with implementing the `Runnable` interface for a class which is more a class that holds information than a worker or so regarding coding style?

Alternativly I could also build a sperate updater which is runnable and executes the `update()` method of a `Boss` object instead of including that in the `Boss` class itself.

Comment: Based on your description, it probably makes more sense to `executor.execute(new Runnable() { run() { boss.update(); } });`

Comment: @assylias Yeah that would also be an option. Now I could say that I always have to create a new runnable object but may be I take that to serious.

Comment: (i) creating a Runnable takes nanoseconds, not milliseconds, so it should not be visible. (ii) you can create a `private final List<Runnable>` and add all the relevant runnables in the list once so you don't have to recreate them on the fly

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with implementing the Runnable interface for a class which is more a class that holds information than a worker or so regarding coding style?

It sounds like you are trying to have one set of classes that hold data and another set of classes that have behaviour. That is a poor design. Object oriented programming is about combining both data and behaviour into one kind of thing (objects).

When it comes to whether a class should implement the `Runnable` interface (or any other interface), the most important thing is to conform to the contract of that interface. That is described by [the JavaDoc for `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread...
>   This interface is designed to provide a common protocol for objects that wish to execute code while they are active... Being active simply means that a thread has been started and has not yet been stopped.

You mentioned using `Executor`, so you do indeed want these instances to be executed by a thread, so `Runnable` is appropriate.